# Sveltekit load_node function error while deploying

Tags: svelte, vercel, sveltekit

I'm trying to deploy my first sveltekit app on vercel. I've followed the steps of using the `adapter-vercel` but I keep getting the error `load function must return a value` whenever I deploy on vercel but also when I run `npm run preview`. I've also tried using different adapters (the static one aswell) but face the same issue.

```
Error: load function must return a value
at load_node (file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/projects/projectname/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1270:13)
at async respond$1 (file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/projects/projectname/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1503:22)
at async render_page (file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/projects/projectname/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1640:20)
at async resolve (file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/projects/projectname/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1827:105)
at async respond (file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/projects/projectname/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1758:22)
at async render_handler (file:///C:/Users/username/Documents/projects/projectname/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index6.js:108:22)
```

I'm not sure if the `load_node` function affects the `load` function or what is exactly meant with it. I've tried tweaking the below code to return errors and status codes and wrapping it in a try catch but nothing seems to change the error I'm getting.

```
<script context="module">
export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {
    const res = await fetch('./pages.json');
    if (res.ok) {
        const { pages } = await res.json();
        return {
            props: { pages }
        };
    }
};
```

I've also tried making the json endpoint static which did not work either. The json endpoint leads to a graphql query:

```
import { client } from '$lib/graphql-client';
import { gql } from 'graphql-request';

export const get = async (req) => {
const slug = req.params.slug;
try {
    const query = gql`
    query Page($slug: String!){
        page(where: {slug:$slug}) {
          title
          content{
            html
          }
        }
      }
    `;

    const variables = { slug };
    const { page } = await client.request(query, variables);

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: { page }
    };
} catch (error) {
    return {
        status: 500,
        body: { error: 'There was a server error.' }
    };
}
```

};

Package.json

```
{
"name": "projectname",
"version": "0.0.1",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "env-cmd svelte-kit dev",
    "build": "svelte-kit build",
    "package": "svelte-kit package",
    "preview": "svelte-kit preview",
    "lint": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --check --plugin-search-dir=. . && eslint --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "format": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write --plugin-search-dir=. ."
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-auto": "^1.0.0-next.27",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-node": "^1.0.0-next.69",
    "@sveltejs/adapter-vercel": "next",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "next",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.4.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.7",
    "cssnano": "^5.0.8",
    "daisyui": "^1.16.2",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^3.2.1",
    "graphql": "^15.7.2",
    "graphql-request": "^3.6.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.9",
    "postcss-load-config": "^3.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.4.0",
    "svelte": "^3.44.0",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.9.8",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.16"
},
"type": "module"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`if (res.ok) {` when the response is not `ok` the load doesn't return a value.

It could be because you're using relative urls "./pages.json" instead of absolute ones like "/pages.json"

Try logging the res.status and (text)contents to see what is wrong when `res.ok` is `false` to debug the issue.